# Markdown editor like on stackexchange

Tags: editor

As a regular user of stackexchange, I really like the markdown editor we have here. With some [additional buttons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187) it is really fun to write articles.

On my Joomla page on the other hand, I usually use the JCE editor which has lots of buttons. However, for including code (I use google codeprettify as well) I still have to switch to html view and input the `pre` tags manually. Additionally, using the usual markdown wrappings for *italics*, **bold**, `inline code`, etc. is faster than pressing some button, so I would like to use this instead.

Is someone using markdown actively with Joomla and can give some tips? Is it possible to have the same editor as here on SE? Additionally, I'm interested in how I can get code blocks working. I tried the [ACE X Markdown Editor (AMD)](http://ext.asikart.com/extensions/asikart-markdown.html) and this didn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried customising the JCE editor - there is a lot you can do

Comment: @tim.baker No, I haven't tried to customize it. I had hoped that the SE editor and its features is so popular that someone who is more knowledgeable as I am in php has already implemented something working.

Comment: I really recommend you go back into JCE and see what's there. It's incredibly powerful and you can easily create your own format style for adding pre and other options, highlight your text and select. Additionally - if you also use NoNumber extensions, you can create custom templates usable through the editor (Content Templater) - and Sourcer lets you add custom code without it getting stripped.

Comment: @REactionFaye Since you are the second one who is suggesting this and since I have read this advice in several other questions: Is there docu on how I can start? Do download the zip of the JCE, unpack it and adjust the code directly there or is there a Git repository? I can surely ask a new question about this, if this beginner information is not already available anywhere.

Comment: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials - there's quite a bit in here, but it's pretty great. I had the pleasure of receiving a tutorial directly from Brian Teeman, but the basics are there. Install JCE, then use the tutorials to customize the component.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen:
https://yoonique.net/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=35&category_id=16&Itemid=118

I haven't used it myself, so can't comment on it's usefulness but I have used one or two of their other products and they are great.

He also has this plugin which converts Markdown Extra.
https://yoonique.net/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=36&category_id=16&Itemid=118

Comment: Yes, I have tried it after the ACE X editor. There, code-blocks are working, although I cannot set the programming language as it is possible [on SE](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212/187). I guess I have to look into the code myself for this. In general, this editor comes close to what I had in mind. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of this extensions:

- [Epic Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/edition/editors/epiceditor-for-joomla)
- [Yoonique Markdown](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/yoonique-markdown)
- [ACE X Markdown](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/edition/editors/ace-x-markdown-editor)

Regards.